# a PHP variable inside a HTML link?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$message = '
<a href="' . $link . '">here</a>
';
?>
```

I'm trying to set $message as a part of mail(). It is suppose to contain a link you can click. 
$link contains the string of the link, but this doesnt work, why? thanks!

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  Have you done `echo $link;` to ensure it contains what you want?  What if you `echo $message` after?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean, "trying to set $message as a part of mail()"? The [PHP mail() documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) doesn't use this wording.

Comment: If you do `echo $message;` in the snippet that have you posted, you should display the link. There is no way that doesn't work.

Comment: Remember that if it’s in an email, it’ll need so start `http://`.

Comment: Also, make sure you use `htmlspecialchars()` on every variable which will be echo'ed to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $message = ?><a href=" <?php echo ' . $link . '?>">here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending an HTML mail than this should work just fine as opposed to a text mail where you would omit the html  and just write the link as it is

#### HTML

```
<a href="somelink"> Click me <a>
```

#### TEXT MAIL

```
www.somelink.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send the Content-Type: text/html; header with mail() like in the HTML-email example at http://php.net/mail

Answer (score 0):

You should use some library to send html emails. Eg. Phpmailer. Sending html emails via mail() is annoying.